# How to make a Value to lowercase in mat-form

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a mat-form from where I want user to enter some values and then I want to submit those values.However I want one of the field to be converted to lowercase and then be submitted.How can I achieve that.

HTML Code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
              <mat-label>Hive Table</mat-label>
              <input
                matInput
                formControlName="hiveTable"
              />
            </mat-form-field>
```

Typescript Code:

```
this.generalInfoForm = new FormGroup({
      hiveTable: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    });
```

What I have tried so far

```
 <mat-label>Hive Table</mat-label>
              <input
                matInput
                oninput="this.value = this.value.toLowerCase()"
                (keyup.enter)="sendit($event.target.value)"
                formControlName="hiveTable"
              />
            </mat-form-field>
```

I used oninout and using keyup I did console.log and in console the values are getting converted tolowercase however on submitting it the value changes back to the way the user typed.
What am I doing wrong.

Comment: It works fine here https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-reactive-form-rhwjnl ..  Click on submit and see console.. Can you reproduce your issue by forking this link if the issue still there??

Answer (score 1):

why not use in input

```
style="text-transform: lowercase"
```

Then, before submit you can (I imagine you has a function submit())

```
submit(form:FormGroup)
{
   if (form.valid)
   {
       form.value.yourField=form.value.yourField.toLowerCase()
       console.log(form.value)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Directive`](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive) as shown below:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[lowercase]'
})
export class LowercaseDirective {

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

    @HostListener('keyup') onKeyUp() {
      const nativeElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
      nativeElement.value = nativeElement.value.toLowerCase();  
    }
}
```

And in your template, this needs to be defined as follows:

```
<input matInput ... lowercase/>
```

Please have a look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lowercase-directive)